# Absolute value symbol with spacing

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Often in math textbooks when they define an absolute value (or a norm in general) they use the symbol with a dot (even nothing) with some space inside. It looks like this:

[image: norm]

Whatever method I use to define the absolute value symbol, normally I would only get a narrow spacing unless I define a new command for this special case. How do you do that?

Comment: In the middle of page 27 of https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf you will find one way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\argordot}[1]{%
    \def\arg{#1}%
    \ifx\arg\empty
        \,\cdot\,%
    \else
        #1%
    \fi%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\lVert}{\rVert}{\argordot{#1}}
\begin{document}
\(\norm{f}\) \(\norm{}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `{}\cdot{}` may be preferable to `\,\cdot\,`, as `\cdot` is generally defined as a binary operator, which should be surrounded by `\medspace`, not `\thinspace` (aka `\,`). Using `{}` is elegant because it hands the decision of how much whitespace to use back to TeX.

Comment: @Mico I just thought it looked better this way, with a little less spacing. Indeed if you use `{}` around `\cdot` you will get the same spacing as if the dot was used as a binary operator, but here we use the dot as the symbol, not as the operator, so I don't see a reason why choosing the precise binary operator spacing would be better.

Answer (score 7):

Irrespective of how you generate the absolute-value and norm "fences" -- be it with `|` and `\|`, named macros such as `\lvert`/`\rvert` and `\lVert`/`\rVert`, or by defining bespoke macros called, say, `\abs` and `\norm` -- the adjustment that's required is always the same: surround `\cdot` with `{}`, aka "empty math atoms", i.e., write `{}\cdot{}`.

For the sake of ensuring notational consistency across the document -- a point made by @egreg in a comment -- it's a good idea not to write `{}\cdot{}` directly. Instead, define a macro called, say, `\blank`, in the preamble and then write `\abs{\blank}` and `\norm{\blank}` in the body of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\[lr][vV]ert" and '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\newcommand{\blank}{{}\cdot{}}
 
\begin{document}
$| \blank | \quad \| \blank \|$

$\lvert \blank \rvert \quad \lVert \blank \rVert$ 

$\abs{\blank} \quad \norm{\blank}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I beg do disagree. Not about `{}\cdot{}` *per se*, however. You *should* recommend first of all to define a special command for this signpost. Then one's free to modify the definition (for example, a coauthor might say that a dash is preferable…)

Comment: Any reason to not do as Vicent and make `\widecdot` (I normally call it `\mtarg`) the default if the arg is empty? (I normally just use `\ifblank{#1}{\mtarg}{#1}` (`etoolbox`)

Comment: +1, but I'd much prefer an “abstract” name; personally I use `\blank` or variations thereon. Not “snazzier”, but carrying semantics.